# String literal not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's a parsing error when i use the string literals below.

```
 <i className{`${icon} icon`} />    


        <h1>text</h1>


 <i className{`${icon} icon`} />
```

Comment: Don't you need `=` for the attribute value?

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting the `=` between the `className` and the value.
change this:

```
<i className{`${icon} icon`} />
```

to this:

```
<i className={`${icon} icon`} />
```

also check that `icon` is defined or you will end up getting a `className` like `'undefined icon'`

Answer (score 1):

You should put a "=" before className:

```
<i className={`${icon} icon`} />    


        <h1>text</h1>


 <i className={`${icon} icon`} />
```